# How to straight a mesh?

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

How can I straight this mesh? without "reconstructing" it...
[image: View]

[image]

Comment: Clarify straiht, look for examples where an object is straight as you want it to be.

Comment: @Leander I want to 'straight' the mesh in a way it is like a tube

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things you can try depending on what straighten means.

- Enter edit Mode, select vertices you want and then choose smooth Vertices
- Subdivide your mesh and apply smooth shading

Comment: I want to 'straight' the mesh in a way it is like a tube

Comment: @CamaileeXD305 have you tried the above suggestions?

Comment: Yeah I try it out, but it wasn't what I expected, well let me explain:
I want to convert that "curved" mesh into a straight one in a way that is completely straight to the X axis. The curved mesh is an arm of my character and I want it to straight it up because I need the arme to be in "T" pose...

Comment: @CamaileeXD305 could you please upload your .blend file on blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com to be able to help you?